# Image sprite - form submit button

Tags: image, forms, sprite

Can i use image sprites for my form submit button, tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

```
.button, .download, .OK, .file{
background: url(app/sprites.png) no-repeat;
 }


.button{
background-position: -1px -212px ;
width: 170px;
height: 30px;
}
```

My form

```
 <form action="add.php" method="post"  value="Username">
 <div style="float:left; margin-left:15px;"><input type="text" name="fbid" required></div>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:2px;"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are missing a class on the input.

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
```

With that it'll work.

I put it into a jsFiddle, using a different image because I don't have access to yours. You can play with the position, in incriments of 32px.

[jsfiddle.net/CzWCv](http://jsfiddle.net/CzWCv)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<div class="button" style="float:left; margin-left:2px;"><input type="submit"
value="Submit"></form>
```

??